# Disable wp_is_mobile()

Tags: functions, mobile

I have a mobile version for my web-site and i used wp_is_mobile(). I will have a button on mobile devices which lets users to switch between the mobile and original versions. Is there a way to disable wp_is_mobile()? Or i can some how trick php to think that the mobile is not a mobile. Thank you for your time.

Note: I don't want to use display: none or other css. I need the content to not appear on mobile version in any ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it other way. I created a new theme for a mobile device and am using a plugin to switch between them.

Answer (score 2):

`wp_is_mobile()` does not have any filters or ways to override.  What you'll need to do is build a wrapper of your own around `wp_is_mobile()` and use that in your code where you've used `wp_is_mobile()`.

Something like the following prototype could work for you. Ultimately a better option over the URL parameter might be to use a cookie value that you set/clear based on the user selected preference. See the PHP documentation on [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for more on cookies.

```
function my_is_mobile() {
    static $is_mobile;

    if (isset($is_mobile)) return $is_mobile;

    if (isset($_REQUEST['mobile']) && $_REQUEST['mobile'] == "no")) {
        $is_mobile = false;
        return $is_mobile;
    }

    $is_mobile = wp_is_mobile();
    return $is_mobile;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time, but i actually solved it already, still upvoting ).

Comment: If you feel this is also a reasonable answer you could also mark it as answering your question.  :)  I'd certainly appreciate the recognition.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you should be dealing with content switching at the CSS level. This can be accomplished in a variety of ways - the most popular of which is mobile-first responsive web design based on viewport width.

Say you had an element with a class of "mobile-hidden" - you could do something like this:

```
.mobile-hidden {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: please read my note

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `wp_is_mobile` in frontend anytime. It's because of caching plugins, it won't work properly if you'd use someone.